# SED removing lines matching several patterns within file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am using SED on macOS to remove all lines in the file matching 2 different patterns within it:

```
# remove all lines containing "WORLD XMAX" and "WORLD YMAX" w/o dublication of the file

sed -i '' -e '/WORLD XMAX/d' -e '/WORLD YMAX/d'  file
```

as the result it removes the first pattern but not the second one. How it could be fixed?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. It removes both lines correctly. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Note that the command will remove any line matching _either_ `WORLD XMAX` _or_ `WORLD YMAX`. Is that what you want? Because your question is asking about removing lines that contain _both_ patterns.

Comment: yes exactly I need to remove all lines matching the both patterns. Normally In my file there are only two lines: one starting from WORLD XMAX and the other one starting from WORLD YMAX. I need to remove both of them. This is what I am doing: sed -i '' -e '/^WORLD XMAX/d' -e '/^WORLD YMAX/d' file

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an example file. Make sure it has lines you should keep and lines you want to delete.

Comment: Right, but what I would like to say that the last version works fine: sed -i '' -e '/^WORLD XMAX/d' -e '/^WORLD YMAX/d' file             I dunno what it the difference between it and what I've indicated in my first topic with the exeption that now I am matching all lines starting with WORLD XMAX or WORLD YMIN

Comment: why dont you break this task into two tasks. first remove WORLD XMAX, then once that is successfully completed, set on the task of removing WORLD YMAX.

Comment: `sed -ni '' -e '/pat1/!p' -e '/pat2/!p'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

`sed -i '/WORLD XMAX/d; /WORLD YMAX/d' file`

sed will match both patterns in each line, and delete it whenever it finds one.